# How to get the sender of an outlook message

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have some code that partially populates an email message as a reply.  But I can not get the sender unless they are on (an / our)? exchange server.

```
Public Sub CreateMessage()

Dim EmailFrom As String
Dim NewMessage As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OldMessage As Outlook.MailItem


Set OldMessage = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set NewMessage = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
EmailFrom = OldMessage.Sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")
NewMessage.Body = Body(EmailFrom)
NewMessage.HTMLBody = HTMLBody(EmailFrom)
NewMessage.Recipients.Add (EmailFrom)
NewMessage.Display
Set NewMessage = Nothing

End Sub
```

The message I receive is "The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" is unknown or cannot be found." and it only appears to work with internal messages.

Anyone know of a way in Outlook VBA to get the sender of a mail message that works for all of them?

---

Fixed based on Dimitry's comments:

```
Public Sub CreateMessage()

Dim EmailFrom As String
Dim NewMessage As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OldMessage As Outlook.MailItem


Set OldMessage = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set NewMessage = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Select Case OldMessage.SenderEmailType
    Case "EX"
        EmailFrom = OldMessage.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Case Else
        EmailFrom = OldMessage.SenderEmailAddress
End Select
NewMessage.Body = Body(EmailFrom)
NewMessage.HTMLBody = HTMLBody(EmailFrom)
NewMessage.Recipients.Add (EmailFrom)
NewMessage.Display
Set NewMessage = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requesting the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property, which is Exchange specific. Check if `SenderEmailType` is "EX" and only then read the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property. Otherwise just read the `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` property.

Take a look at the message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage) to see the available properties.

Comment: And in case of Exchange, you might want to use MailItem,Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress instead (with checks for nulls of course) - PR_SMTP_ADDRESS is not guaranteed to be available.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I need to check SenderEmailType.  If the type is "EX" then I must use the code I posted, otherwise Dmitry's solution works perfectly.