# How to reference item that triggers ItemAdd?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to send a message to my phone when I receive mail at work.

The macro should send mail to an sms service that converts the mail to an sms and sends it to my phone. The message will contain the mail sender address and the send and receive times.

I have put together two macros I found by searching the internet.

The first code is on this link [tachytelic.net](https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/)

The second I found here
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367448/how-to-get-the-sender-of-an-outlook-message)

Here is the part of the code that fails.

```
'variable for select case
Dim EmailFrom As String
Dim OldMessage As Outlook.MailItem

Set OldMessage = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

'Puts sender mail address in variable both ordinary mail and Exchange emails.
Select Case OldMessage.SenderEmailType
    Case "EX"
       EmailFrom = OldMessage.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Case Else
       EmailFrom = OldMessage.SenderEmailAddress
End Select

'Sends E-mail to sms service.
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .To = "some@mail.com"
        .Subject = "You got a new E-mail!"
        .Body = EmailFrom & vbCrLf & "Sendt: " & Item.SentOn & vbCrLf & "Modtaget: " & Item.ReceivedTime
        .Send
    End With
End If
```

I get

> runtime error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set.

I tried to use the F8 key but that isn't possible, I don't know why.

Then I took the original code and pasted it in a module. Then I can use the F8 key to go through the code.

The error comes when I reach this line.

```
Set OldMessage = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

Here is the whole code

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  
  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'variable for if statments
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'variable for select case
Dim EmailFrom As String
Dim OldMessage As Outlook.MailItem

'Deletes sms status mails I recieve when I mail to sms service
If InStr(Item.Subject, "SMS status") > 0 Then
    Item.UnRead = False
    Item.Save
    Item.Delete
    End
End If

'Puts sender mail address in variable both ordinary mail and Exchange emails.
Select Case OldMessage.SenderEmailType
    Case "EX"
       EmailFrom = OldMessage.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Case Else
       EmailFrom = OldMessage.SenderEmailAddress
End Select

'Sends E-mail to sms service.
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .To = "some@mail.com"
        .Subject = "You got a new E-mail!"
        .Body = EmailFrom & vbCrLf & "Sendt: " & Item.SentOn & vbCrLf & "Modtaget: " & Item.ReceivedTime
        .Send
    End With
End If

ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

Then it is easier to get an overview.

How do I get the ActiveInspector to se the recieved mail and save it in the OldMessage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no open item window of any kind, ActiveInspector will be Nothing.  Also, based on your supplied code sample, the Item variable is not declared or set anywhere, so you'll likely also get an error on this line:

```
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
```

Comment: But if I comment out the select case and the variables to it. the code runs fine with the Item variable. When I recieve an email I get an sms that tels me that "you got new mail send/recieve time" so I added the select case so that I can see who it is from.

Comment: The Item variable is declared  in the  "Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)"

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Now it's clear that you are deleting the email that's passed as the Item parameter in the ItemAdd event, and you're not setting the OldMessage variable to anything at all. ActiveInspector is of no use - it's only for open items. The email that's being added to that folder is not opened.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I accidently removed the line of code that causes the problem. Underneath "Dim OldMessage As Outlook.MailItem" there shouldt have been "Set OldMessage = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem". What do you mean that I'm deleting the mail that is passed as the Item. I only delete the Item if it contains "SMS status" in the subject line. But how do I get the Item.

I have tryed to make a "Dim olType As Outlook.MailItem" and "Set olType = Item.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem" insted og the OldMessage. Then I get this error 438 - Object doesn't support this proberty or method.

Comment: You already have access to the Item object - you are even reading its properties. If you want to cast that to a MailItem variable, just add "Set OldMessage = Item". Again, you CANNOT USE ActiveInspector - the item is NOT open in its own Inspector window.

Comment: Eric Legault Thanks for your help and time. It works now.

Comment: Hi again Eric. What if I want to check mails not only in the inbox but also in sub folders.

Comment: Create another event handler for the Items.ItemAdd event for that folder's Items collection